# On- and off-topic questions: Microhistory

Tags: discussion

I have a habit of asking for background information for particular questions that come up in my research.  My newest one is:

[At what ages did British students enroll in school in the late 1800s and early 1900s?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/5521/at-what-ages-did-british-students-enroll-in-school-in-the-late-1800s-and-early-1)

What content would you like to see in this type of question that would make it more appropriate for our site, instead of History.SE?

I've parked some links in the comments for later, but would it be better to rewrite the question entirely in the form "how can I find records about my British Ancestors' school attendance" and put the information about the collection on FindMyPast as an answer?

Should I visit my other 'microhistory' questions and recast them in that fashion?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure that there is any necessity to revisit earlier 'microhistory' questions but I do think the revised title and slant that you suggest for this one helps to put it on the G&FH side of the line between [General History](http://history.stackexchange.com) and [Family History](http://genealogy.stackexchange.com).

This is only an aside but with respect to your new title "how can I find records about my British Ancestors' school attendance", I have gone away from using title starters like "How to" or "How can I" in titles so I'll suggest some more concise ones like:

- "Finding records about British Ancestors' school attendance?"
- "Finding when 19th century ancestor attended school in Devon, England?"

I came to this way of thinking from reading Q&As like the "poorly titled :-)" [How do I write a good title?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10648/215590)